# Changing the color of dropdown items in TDBLookupComboBox

Tags: delphi

I want to change the color of the dropdown items in a TDBLookupComboBox (in Delphi 2007).  This seems to be non-trivial due to the lack of an OnDrawItem event.  Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't look like it.  The easiest way would probably be to create a new control that descends from TDBLookupComboBox and implement an OnDrawItem event on it.  You could probably copy the code pretty much wholesale from TComboBox.  Just make sure to test it well...

Comment: Dude, this is not the answer I want, although it's pretty much along the lines of what I was thinking - but you can have an up vote for honesty.